# 'Collection' object is not iterable

Tags: python, arrays, mongodb, object

Welcome
I have a database and in it there is a collection called products, and inside it is an object and inside it is a group of my opinions, and I am supposed to call the entire object

but i faces these error

```
in __next__
    raise TypeError("'Collection' object is not iterable")
TypeError: 'Collection' object is not iterable
```

my code:

```
links = db["products"]["rent"]["cameras"]["canon"]["pictures"]
        for link in links:
           print(link)
```

Comment: if `links` is a collection you have to extract results from that collection and iterate over the results. You can't iterate directly over the collection. Try with `for link in links.find()` maybe

Comment: [PyMongo Tutorial](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html) - this has examples on how to connect to the MongoDB server, get a database and collection, and then how to query the collection.

Answer (score 2):

Append the .find() method to make the collection iterable

```
links = db["..."]["..."].find()
for link in links:
   print(link)
```